# How to get the language of the file according to its extension?

Tags: api, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am having problem on this one, How to find the language of the file according to its extension using the vscode API? i tried `vscode.languages.getLanguages` but I don't think that's the right one.

Comment: `editor.document.languageId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean get the targeted opened-file's language?For that you can use `window.activeTextEditor?.document.languageId` .The docs are [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window).

`vscode.languages.getLanguages` is the API that get the vscode's registered language,in other words,get the language list that vscode can recognize.If you want to know the opened file's language,you should use `window.activeTextEditor?.document.languageId`.

Also,you can use the event `vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor` with it to keep you always get the opened-file's language.

For instance,in my extension,I code like this:

```js
//When the texteditor change,it will be called
private initialListener(){
  vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor(this.theScheduler["changeLanguage"])
}
```

`theScheduler` is a object like this:

```js
{
 changeLanguage:function(){
    let text = window.activeTextEditor?.document.languageId; //Get the targeted file's language
//do something
}
```

My extension's source code are [here](https://github.com/WendaoLee/vscode-asoul_codehelper),you can view it as a reference. I'm sorry that the code's annotation is chinese friendly,do hope it can help you some.